# OpenSceneGraph can't locate library dependency

Tags: linux, libraries

I've completed the installation instructions for OpenSceneGraph, including installation of OpenThreads from source. However, the osgviewer is unable to locate the file it needs to run.

```
$ /usr/local/bin/osgviewer
/usr/local/bin/osgviewer: error while loading shared libraries: libOpenThreads.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
$ ls -l /usr/local/lib64 | grep libOpenThreads
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      20 Jul 13 16:55 libOpenThreads.so -> libOpenThreads.so.20
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      23 Jul 13 16:55 libOpenThreads.so.20 -> libOpenThreads.so.3.3.0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root      23 Jul 13 15:12 libOpenThreads.so.21 -> libOpenThreads.so.3.3.1
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   49688 Jul 13 16:55 libOpenThreads.so.3.3.0
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   44464 Jul 13 02:59 libOpenThreads.so.3.3.1
```

Is there a way to determine where this program is looking for the library so I can make a symlink? Is it tied to a path-like envar?

Answer (score 2):

To see which directories are in the library search path.

```
ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
```

Most likely */usr/lib* is already in the library search path.

Then create a symbolic link.

```
cp -s /usr/local/lib64/libOpenThreads.so.21 /usr/lib
```

If you want to add */usr/local/lib64* to library search path, add it to */etc/ld.conf.so* and run *ldconfig*.

Comment: Interestingly these are the results I get, _/usr/lib_ and _/usr/lib64_ aren't one of them, but somehow there are many subdirectories of _/usr/lib64_ listed. 
`$ ldconfig -v 2>/dev/null | grep -v ^$'\t'
/usr/lib64/atlas:
/usr/lib64/dyninst:
/usr/lib64/iscsi:
/usr/lib64/mysql:
/usr/lib64/qt-3.3/lib:
/lib:
/lib64:
/lib/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
/lib64/sse2: (hwcap: 0x0000000004000000)
/lib64/tls: (hwcap: 0x8000000000000000)`
Is this normal for CentOS 7?

Comment: I think it's ok. I have never used CentOS though.

Comment: Here someone had outputs similar to you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9922949/how-to-print-the-ldlinker-search-path